# Typewriter library | How to add < & > in typeString()?

Tags: reactjs, typewriter

I want to escape < and > characters within the typeString() method in Typewriter.

I've tried using the escape characters, but it does not seem to work.

This is the code I'm writing.

```
<Typewriter
      onInit={(typewriter) => {
        typewriter
          .typeString("<div>import Aadesh from 'org'</div>")
          .pauseFor(1500)
          .typeString("<div>const App() =&#62; &#60; Aadesh /&#62; </div>")
          .start();
      }}
    />
```

It does not convert `&#60;` to < and `&#62;` to >.
I've also tried using `&lt;` & `&gt;` but it hasn't worked.

**Expected output from typewriter:**

```
import Aadesh from 'Org' 
const App() => <Aadesh />
```

**Actual output form typewriter**

```
import Aadesh from 'Org' 

const App() => `&lt;` Aadesh /`&gt;`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a string with html tags to the `typeString()`, the library treats the entire string as a single entity and does not parse or render the tags. This is why `&lt;` and `&gt;` are not being converted to `<` and `>`. If that so, use js built-in string methods to replace the entities with the actual characters before passing the string to the `typeString()`.

Example;

```
<Typewriter
 onInit={(typewriter) => {
   typewriter
     .typeString("<div>import Aadesh from 'org'</div>")
     .pauseFor(1500)
     .typeString("<div>const App() =&#62; &#60; Aadesh /&#62; </div>".replace(/&#60;/g, '<').replace(/&#62;/g, '>'))
     .start();
 }}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I still didn't understand why it wouldn't work if < and > is used directly instead.